# How to Show/Hide Table Object Columns

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working in iReport 5.6.0.  I am creating a report base utilizing a table and would like to build one or more options to hide a series of columns; effectively creating a master report which will allow users to have multiple report views based on a simple parameter selection.  In theory, this should work.   However, I am having a problem passing a parameter from the main report it the table (where I am would use it to activate the Column Print When property.

To be clear.  I have created an outer parameter and an inner parameter.  I have also successfully mapped the parameters.  I know that the mapping is working as I have added a column to my table and placed the parameter within the data row so that I can visually evaluate it--this too, works.  However, when I set the Column Print When property  as

```
$P{parameter1_1}.equals("y")
```

or even

```
$P{parameter1_1}.equals('y')
```

and then preview the report, I receive the following error:

```
Parameter not found:  Description: parameter1_1   Object:  fx $P{parameter1_1}.equals("y")
```

Comment: It is better to post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem